# Swtich case in JQuery

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, parent

I am experimenting this small code. The idea is I place tag  inside each distinguish tag and use the parent() method to store the string value in switch so that this guy will match each case and output the coresponding answer. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> <button>Button in a div</button> </div>
       <span> <button>Button in a span</button> </span>
     <strong> <button>Button in a strong</button> </strong>
       <p>    <button>Button in a p</button> </p>
      <table> <button>Button in a table</button> </table>
    <p id='info'></p>
    <script>
      $('button').click(function(){
      var x = $(this).parent()
      switch(x){
        case "div":
        $('#info').html('You pressed button whose parent is div')
        break
        case "span":
        $('#info').html('You pressed button whose parent is span')
        break
        }
        )}
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

There are only 2 cases in this, because i'm not sure if the code works or not so yeah, time is gold. I didn't type them all but i hope you guys understand what I am getting at....And sorry for the messy presentation, i'm kinda new to this web developing stuff.

Comment: So...have you tested your code? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I'll tell you the end of the story: your code doesn't work :) `parent` is not a string

Comment: You need to test it out *before* asking for help on SO.  Our "time is gold" too.

Comment: ouch i forgot to mention that i have tested my code and It didn't work, sorry :((

Comment: learning how to write the code is only part of the game...more important to know how to do basic debugging using the tools that are built right into your browser

Comment: @sharf ouch this made my question bad.... this should open my eyes too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tagName should give you the actual tag name of the parent element.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var x = $(this).parent().tagName;
  switch(x){
    case "div":
      $('#info').html('You pressed button whose parent is div');
      break;
    case "span":
      $('#info').html('You pressed button whose parent is span');
      break;
  }
)};
```

Comment: `tagName` is a JS property so you need `$(this).parent()[0].tagName` and it might be uppercase so `$(this).parent()[0].tagName.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Amazing :S the tagName. I guess I'll need to spend more time  digging into JQuery. Thank you so much for opening my eyes.

Comment: @ChuQuang Check the tick to mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem. Upvote (click the upwards arrow) if you think the answer is good.

Comment: or use `prop('tagName').toLowerCase()`

Comment: ok thank you @lenz :D I'm 10 minutes old to this site so I still need to figure out how it works